# The customlistview doesn't populate the list of files,that i want to?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager, custom-adapter

I am trying to populate mp3files in a custom listview inside a fragment, which in turn is a part of viewpager. Here is the code of the fragment in which I want to place the list view:

```
public class FragmentSongs extends  Fragment {

    private static final String Sd_Path=new String("/sdcard/");
    private MediaPlayer mp =new MediaPlayer();




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        ListView SngList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.SongList);

         SongDetails Detail = null ;
         Context _c = null ;



         ArrayList<SongDetails> Songinfo;

         // AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
         Songinfo = new ArrayList<SongDetails>();

         File f=new File("/system/");
         File[] files = f.listFiles(new Mp3Filter());
         if( files.length>0)
         {
              for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) 
              {Detail.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
              Detail.setSong(files[i].getName());
              Detail.setArtist(files[i].getName());
              Detail.setAlbum(files[i].getName());
              Songinfo.add(Detail);

              SngList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(Songinfo ));


              }
         }
         else  if (files.length == 0)
             return null;

         return view;


    } 
}

class Mp3Filter implements FilenameFilter{
    public boolean accept(File dir,String name)
    {

        return (name.endsWith(".rc"))|| (name.endsWith(".Mp3")) ||
                      (name.endsWith(".MP3"));//searching for the files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( files.length>0) {
      for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++)  {
          SongDetails detail = new SongDetails();
          detail.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
          detail.setSong(files[i].getName());
          detail.setArtist(files[i].getName());
          detail.setAlbum(files[i].getName());
          Songinfo.add(detail);
       }
     SngList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(Songinfo ));
 }
```

in the for loop two things are wrong. The first you create at every iteration a new `CustomAdapter`. Yoph should crate and set it when the loop runs out. The secondo mistake is that you, at every iteration override the values of Detail. You should create a new `Detail` object at every iteratio

Comment: but the adapter is outside the for loop

Comment: and Detail is already an object of type SongDetail,if you wan't i can place the source code of Songdetail for you to review?

Comment: wait `SngList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(Songinfo ));` is inside the for loop. You have to create a new Detail for every iteration

Comment: thanx for the loop thing,i was looking at your code and thought it was mine so i made that comment"but the adapter is outside the for loop"
i am not sure about the detail thing though,let me give it a try and i will tell you in a minute

Comment: it is giving an error because Detail is already an an object of the class 
SongDetails Detail = null ;

Comment: I will edit my code. I wrote `Detail detail = new Detail();` but it has to be  `SongDetails detail = new SongDetails();`

Comment: It should be `Detail = new SongDetails();`. OP has declared `SongDetails Detail = null;` outside the for-loop.

Comment: @vikram I already edited my answer. Still a new object has to be create at every iteration. Also for the name java convention, objects name should starts with a lowercase letter

Comment: result is still the same,nothing is loading,( i will like to mention that the path i am using is "/system/" instead of "/sdcard/" because of permission issues in the avd,also i am serching for files ".rc" there are two files in the system with the extension ".rc" i hope this thing won't create any problems?it still has to return the".rc" files right?

Comment: I can list files inside /system but, probably, not all the subidrs are accessible

Comment: tested on the phone having mp3 files,still the same :(

Comment: but you have the files inside /system or inside a subdir of system?

Comment: Yes, but it seems that Android developers these days(and, especially on this site) have made it a point to start their references with a capital letter. Annoys me quite a bit. Don't books on Android programming touch on java naming conventions at all?

Comment: there is a permission issue with my avd so i was using the path"/system/" as i can't put files in its sdcard 

but just now i changed the path path to "/sdcard/" and ran it on a   friend's phone and still it didn't populate the list

Comment: @vikram can you provide a url where the talk about this matter?

Comment: blackbelt please see my answer as you may have missed it.

Comment: @Ankit two things. First you have to list a path that contains files that end with .Mp3 or .rc or .MP3, otherwise the filter will return nothing. The second endsWith is case sensitive

Comment: @Ankit are you sure that inside /system exists at least one file that ends with .rc or .Mp3 or .MP3 ?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34647/java-naming-conventions.. @Ankit join for help

Comment: yup,thats what i am saying,first i used "/system" on the avd it has 2 
".rc" files, 
then i used "/sdcard" on my phone which has plenty of mp3 files.

Comment: Dunno how,it wasn't working yesterday,tuday when i started my pc and i found ,its working :)